# Image coordinate transformation equations

Tags: image

The Wolfram [tutorial for image processing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html.en) gives these equations 
to convert between an image y coordinate and an array row index, r

```
r==h-y+1/2

y==h-r-1/2
```

But these equations are not algebraically consistent. If you solve the first for *y*, you don't get the second!

It seems to me that *h* is used differently in the two equations. In the first equation *h* is actually the number of array rows, and in the second it's really the number of rows+1, which corresponds to the depiction of *h* in the earlier figures of the tutorial as the topmost "coordinate" in an image.  If this is so, surely a different letter should be used.

Is there really this very basic error in the documentation? Or am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a mistake. The first equation should be $r = h - (y+1/2)$.

The continuous domain covers $[0,w]\times[0,h]$. Pixels are a discretization of the space. As the existence of both `ImageValuePositions` and `PixelValuePositions` shows, there are two different ways to specify pixels. If you specify a pixel by its coordinate then the bottom left pixel is $(0.5, 0.5)$. If you specify a pixel by its indices, it will be $(x_p,y_p) = (x+0.5, y+0.5)$ where $(x,y)$ are the corresponding coordinates. That is, the bottom left pixel will be specified by $(1,1)$.

In the formulas you mention, $y$ is the pixel coordinate. $y_p = y+0.5$ is the corresponding index. If $r=0$ then we see that, according to the first equation, $y-1/2 = h$. This is wrong because in this case $y$ is a coordinate outside the domain. We know that the index should be $y_p = h$, and therefore we can see that the equation should be $y+1/2 = h$.

It would perhaps have been clearer to write the equations in terms of the pixel indices, in this case the equations are
$$
r = h - y_p,\quad y_p= h -r.
$$

Comment: Thanks. These off-by-one bugs are painful. In some way they are the hardest bugs to appreciate because they deal with things that seem, on the surface, to be so simple.